# Find the Max Length of two Columns Combined

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have a Customers table with the columns FirstName and LastName - I assume have to concatenate the two columns in order to find out the longest customer name. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, FirstName, LastName, LEN(FirstName + LastName)
FROM Customers
ORDER BY LEN(FirstName + LastName) DESC;
```

Where ID is your primary key. This will give you the id, firstname, lastname and length of the longest concatenated name.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you the longest name in the DB:

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(FirstName) + LEN(LastName)) AS MaxLen 
from Customers
```

Answer (score 2):

This will tell you the length of each customer's name:

```
SELECT LEN(FirstName) + LEN(LastName) as TotalLength from Customers
```

Comment: Ah of course. ORDER BY FirstName DESC, LastName DESC would give me the highest length I guess

Comment: No - ORDER BY LEN(FirstName + LastName) DESC - would put the longest concatenated name in the first row.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM names order by ( length(first_name)  + length(last_name)) desc limit 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstName, lastName 
FROM Customers t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Len(firstName) + Len(lastName)) longest FROM Customers) t2
ON Len(t1.firstName) + Len(t1.lastName) = longest
```